# Compiling object oriented fortran with gfortran

Tags: oop, fortran, gfortran

I'm struggling getting a simple object oriented program to work.

I have a module in a file testmod.f:

```
  module testmod
    implicit none

  type testobject
      real :: X
  contains
      procedure, public, pass(this) :: initialize
      procedure :: print
  end type testobject

  contains
    subroutine initialize(this, x)
      class(testobject) :: this
      real :: x

      this%X = x
    end subroutine initialize

    subroutine print(this)
        class(testobject) :: this
        print *, this%x
    end subroutine print
  end module testmod
```

And to test the code I've got this test-program:

```
   program test
     use testmod
     type(testobject) :: testobj

     call testobj%initilize(0.0)
   end program test
```

I compile the module using gfortran:

```
gfortran -ffree-form testmod.f -shared
```

And the testprogram:

```
gfortran -ffree-form test.f
```

The result of the last gfortran call is as follows:

```
/tmp/ccGPbBvF.o: In function `MAIN__':
test.f:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `__testmod_MOD___vtab_testmod_Testobject'
test.f:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `__testmod_MOD_initialize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I on the other hand calls testobj%initilize("x") I get an error for not calling the subroutine with a real, as expected.

I guess I should call gfortran in a different matter?

Comment: You have to link with the module object. We surely have a duplicate. You can also just compile both files in one command.

Comment: I thought the compiler would find the .mod files in the current directory. Compiling it all in once, as you suggest works. But the reason for doing it as I'm trying to do is to get this to work with pFunit. All my other source code will compile the way I have showed above Except the newly added one using objects. The above example is an extract. Compiling the .f file containing the module with the -c option to get an object file also works. That might be what I need to do in pFunit as well.

Comment: The .mod files does NOT contain the compiled code. It only contains the description of all the interfaces. When you compile your object file or a shared library, you have to link it.

Comment: When you do `gfortran -ffree-form testmod.f -shared` the result is a shared library named `a.out`. You probably want  `gfortran -ffree-form testmod.f -shared -o libmy_library.so`. And then you want to place the library in a convenient place and link it with `-lmy_library.so` when needing it.